# How to change lower case to upper using regular expressions in Visual Studio Code

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.14.2, and I'm trying to change name of variables to camelCase eg.
`set_nominal_wavelength` to `setNominalWavelength`.

Regular expression: `_([a-z])`

Replace: `\U$1\E`

does not work. Any idea how to achieve it?

Comment: Use Notepad++, it will work there.

Comment: Ok. But is it possible in VScode?

Comment: No, it is not possible. Why not just write some C#/JS/PHP etc. code to handle that? It is really a very common issue that can easily be solved with a bit of code. Well, or, as I say, just download a free copy of NPP and enjoy this solution.

Comment: Well, I've changed it using `sed` in terminal. Just been curious if it's possible in VScode.

Comment: Good question❗️ I shouldn't need go out from VSCode to do such simple Regex transformation 

Comment: Using latest version of VSCode worked for me for replacing

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There is a workaround:

1. Open Replace dialog and enter regex: `_([a-z])`
2. Then move focus to the editor area and press Ctrl+F2 ("Change All Occurrences")
3. Then change case of selection (Ctrl+P >upper)
4. Then press Left Arrow key and press Delete key

Comment: Too bad you can't do this if you're working with global search though.

Comment: Saved me soo much time

Comment: For Mac OS it is CMD+F2  and CMD+Shift+p

Comment: for windows 10, it is Ctrl+F2 and Ctrl+Shift+p

Comment: Check out Mark's submission below because this limitation has since been resolved in recent VS Code updates. I just confirmed that working as of today (v 1.60.2 - MacOS)

Answer (score 64):

As of vscode v1.75 there is a `Transform to Camel Case` command.  So you could

1. Find: `(_[a-z]+)+`
2. `Alt+Enter` will select all those
3. trigger the `Transform to Camel Case` command

Pretty easy.

---

In the 1.47 Insiders Build support for the replace case modifiers (`\L`, `\l`, `\U`, `\u`) has been added to vscode.  And so should be in the 1.47 stable release).

So simply doing your find: `_([a-z])`

and replace with `\u$1` (since you only want to capitalize the first letter)  works nicely in the Insiders Build now.

[image: case modifier demo]

Works in both the Find Widget and the Search Panel.

Comment: No need for a snippet here.  You can just use ctrl-shift-l, then press escape to clear the find dialog, then use to-uppercase command via pallet.

Comment: Sounds like two extra steps though - open the command palette, type to find the command, and trigger it.  Instead of just triggering the snippet command.  That is assuming you will want to camelCase in the future.

Comment: Creating a snippet is a lot more steps if this is a one-off thing you need to do.  If you are regularly converting between snake_case and camelCase, then the snippet is probably the better solution.

Comment: What a nice animated gif!

Comment: What software did you use to create this gif? Thanks.

Comment: The keystroke visibility is through vscode's own setting: `Toggle Screencast Mode` and for the gif I use https://www.screentogif.com/ which works well enough but sometimes gets confused by keystroke input.  There are 2 vscode `screencast` settings to look at too: `vertical offset` and `Only Keyboard Shortcuts` (so just control keychords are shown not everything like text you might type).

Comment: The support for replace case modifiers in VS Code Insiders is great, but unfortunately it doesn't work when replacing text across the entire workspace (Ctrl+Shift+H). The older solution also appears to only work when replacing in a single file.

Comment: @Rudey After your comment, support for case modifiers was added  to the search across files panel.

Comment: This functionality is now in mainline VSCode.

Comment: Confirming that it works in regular VSCode now.

Answer (score 2):

You may use other tools that support change case operators, like Notepad++, `sed`, R (`gsub` with `perl=TRUE`), but VS Code does not support these operators in the replacement pattern.

See [this feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12185):

> This is cool to have. This is beyond the scope of what is currently supported by javascript.
>
> We need to come up with our own advanced replace engine to support these cases.